# Batch file to configure notepad settings

Tags: windows, batch, notepad

I have plain text (.txt) reports, in order to be printed correctly (final users will print the report). I need to configure notepad settings. as:

margins:

`let: 8
 right: 8
 top: 4
 bottom: 4`

font:

`font: Consolas
 Style: Normal
 Size: 11`

How can I configure it automatically at open notepad, or at least on executing a .bat file. Or any suggestion to avoid users printing incorrectly.

Working on windows10

Comment: Notepad doesn't support margins...

Comment: Margin for printing: File>page setup..>margins

Comment: Ah yes, ok. Looks like there are very limited command line options. 

/A <filename> open file as ansi
/W <filename> open file as unicode
/P <filename> print filename
/PT <filename> <printername> <driverdll> <port> print filename to designated printer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notepad settings are in the registry at key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad`.

You may use `regedit` to export your own settings to a `.reg` file,
then import them into the other computers either by the menu *File > Import..*,
or by executing the `.reg` file, or by the command
[reg import](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-import).